# Euclidean Rings, Extension of Integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] : d \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is the case that $R$ is always a Euclidean ring, if we consider the norm function $\delta(x + \sqrt{d}y) = x^{2} + d y^{2}$.

Comment: Note:  usually the norm $x^2-dy^2$ is used

Answer (score 2):

No $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is not a Euclidean domain in general with the norm function $N(x+\sqrt{d})=x^2-dy^2$.

If it were, noting that Euclidean Domain $\implies$ PID $\implies$ UFD tells us we should get unique factorisation.

A common example would be to check $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a UFD by showing that
$2\cdot 3=(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$. Computing the norms shows us that these elements are in fact irreducibles but the factorisation is distinct (in the sense that $2$ and $1\pm\sqrt{-5}$ do not differ by a unit)